# Required Login Session to Run HTTP Request in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

**Precondition:** Need To Login Application first, then I can send my API request to the server, so who can set this thing in Jmeter?

**Current:** I am getting error as

> "{"Message":"Request was not made within the context of a valid
>   session.","Data":"ErrorId: "}"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager) to your Test Plan, if the "session" is being handled by cookies - the Cookie Manager will automatically resolve it.

If not - then most probably you will need to perform **correlation** - the process of detecting dynamic element(s), extracting them into [JMeter Variable(s)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) using a suitable [JMeter PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and replacing recorded hard-coded value in the next request with the JMeter Variable.

Example test plan outline:

- Request 1

  - Post Processor to extract token from the Request 1 into variable `token`
- Request 2 sending `${token}` from the request 1 as a parameter

You can consider an alternative way of recording a JMeter test using cloud-based proxy service, it is capable of exporting recorded scripts in "SmartJMX" format which automatically detects and handles dynamic parameters. See [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

To do Basic Auth, just add [HTTP Authorization Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) to your plan as per this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication/12563623#12563623

It would be configured like this if your server URL is **http://localhost:8080/test**:

[image: Http Authorization Manager]

There is no need for scripting here.